# Community Connector that can connect to SAS platform

Tags: looker-studio

Is there any community connector available in Google Data Studio that can help to connect to SAS platform.

Or do I need to create my own connector to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0):

If this is an existing service perhaps they already built a connector. If this is your own SaaS you will need to write your own.